# Sqoop - Could not find or load main class org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, hive, sqoop

I installed **Hadoop**, **Hive**, **HBase**, **Sqoop** and added them to the PATH.

When I try to execute `sqoop` command, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop
```

**Development Environment:**

OS : Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit

Hadoop Version: 1.0.4

Hive Version: 0.9.0

Hbase Version: 0.94.5

Sqoop Version: 1.4.3

Answer (score 16, accepted):

make sure you have sqoop-1.4.3.jar under your SQOOP HOME directory.

Note : May be because you had downloaded wrong distribution under [Sqoop Distribution](http://www.apache.org/dist/sqoop/1.4.3/)

Comment: thanks for your answer; right distribution is `sqoop-x.y.z.bin__hadoop.a.b.c`; now it's working.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Why doesn't the `sqoop-x-jar` come along with the sqoop installation directory? Strange!

Comment: I too got in  both way , either paste jar file or use sqoop-x.y.z.bin__hadoop.a.b.c file

Comment: Why there are two different files, then?

Answer (score 7):

I have resolved this issue on CentOS 6.3.
I have Hadoop-1.0.4, hbase-0.94.6, hive-0.10.0, pig-0.11.1, sqoop-1.4.3.bin__hadoop-1.0.0, zookeeper-3.4.5 installed.

I was also running same problem at sqoop: `Error - Could not find the main class: org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop`.

To resolve this issue I have copied the jar file: `sqoop-1.4.3.jar` from `$SQOOP_HOME/` into the `$HADOOP_HOME/lib/`.

Hope this would help someone who struggling sqoop to be work with hadoop.

Comment: when i install with cdh distribution, copy sqoop jar from SQOOP_HOME to HADOOP_HOME/lib works, thanks a lot.

Comment: only if `sqoop-1.4.3.jar` shown in the `$SQOOP_HOME/lib`, it works.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I didn't find a complete answer for my problems. Current sqoop installation version I used was 1.4.6 . I am not sure about sqoop-1.4.6.tar.gz if one has to compile the source code,  I was able to beat the same error `Error - Could not find the main class: org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop` using following instructions:

Instead I downloaded `sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha.tar.gz` from apache sqoop and installed it at `/home/ubuntu/SQOOP/` renamed `sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha` to `sqoop`. I wanted to use with Yarn.

Then export and set $SQOOP_HOME
I used this

`export SQOOP_HOME=/home/ubuntu/SQOOP/sqoop/`

`export PATH=$PATH:$SQOOP_HOME/bin`

Now if one go to $SQOOP_HOME/bin and try

```
./sqoop help
```

It should work without any issue.

Comment: Thank you! These instructions helped me

Answer (score 2):

The problem in my case was that `hadoop-env.sh` file has this line in it:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar
```

It seems that when you call `sqoop` it internally calls `configure-sqoop` which sets the `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` correctly but then when it (sqoop) calls `hadoop`, `hadoop` ignores that variable and reset it back to what is in `hadooop-env.sh`

The fix was to change the `hadoop-env.sh` to have this line instead:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH="${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH"
```

Comment: There seems to be also a typo in the version I downloaded: sqoop 1.4.6 - hadoop 2.0.4. It originally says JACA_HOME. I corrected it to JAVA_HOME and applied the solution above. It all worked!

Answer (score 0):

@user225003 solution magically worked and I looked into some of the files and here is what happens under the hood when you execute "sqoop" script.

The "**sqoop**" script essentially executes "**hadoop**" script from `$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/bin/` directory. While configuring sqoop, in "`sqoop-env.sh`" we set the `$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME` to hadoop installation directory. If your sqoop and hadoop installations are not in regular location `/usr/local`, I believe `sqoop-x.x.x.jar` is not in the hadoop script's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Download sqoop-1.4.7.jar file from [here](https://talend-update.talend.com/nexus/content/repositories/libraries/org/apache/sqoop/sqoop/1.4.7/), and move it to $SQOOP_HOME/lib